# Never-Ending Maven Issues

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've inherited a badly written Java/Spring project. I'm using Eclipse STS as an IDE. Every time I'm trying to set up another computer for development, I'm entering a world of pain. After a lot of tinkering and fighthing, I've narrowed the problem down to one reoccurring issue - Maven's Repository.

I've opened the project in STS on a new computer. The project won't build, because it claims some Spring jar is missing or invalid. The file is there ( in the .m2) directory. Deleting it an updating the Maven dependencies downloads a correct version of the file, and the error disappears. Only to be replaced with another error, about another jar file.

After repeating the process several times, I no longer get the invalid jar file error. Instead I got a strange error saying `assembly` is an invalid XML element.

I delete the .m2 folder entirely and let Maven repopulate it, the error has not disappeared. Only after I copied the .m2 folder from another computer (where the project does compile and work) did the problem disappear.

There are no Maven related errors in the Eclipse error log. All I see are compilation errors in the Problems pane.

Why does Maven keep downloading corrupted JAR files? And how can I avoid this problem every time?

CLARIFICATION: We're not using a proxy, and we do not experience any networking issues downloading any other file. Python's `pip`, Node's `npm`, Microsoft's `nuget` and even `bower` all work flawlessly, several times a day, sometimes on projects just as big. This is a Maven only issue, and numerous machines.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
I'm using STS 3.9.0.RELEASE (which is based on Eclipse 4.6.3). I'm using the STS embedded Maven, which is version 3.3.9/1.7.0.20160603-1931 (that's a very elaborate version number, I'm not sure exactly what it means...).

I do not have a ~/.m2/settings.xml file (I deleted the entire .m2 directory)

Here is the repositories section from pom.xml:

```
<repositories>

    <!-- For main Spring releases -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <name>JBoss repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>


    <repository>
        <id>Servlet-api</id>
        <name>Servlet-api repository</name>
        <!-- <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/</url> -->
        <url>http://search.maven.org/</url>
    </repository>


</repositories>
```

Comment: Too many variables at play here unfortunately. Seems like some local maven settings or STS settings could be at play. Do you have a standalone maven installed on your machine? does running the build from the command line works? does STS add some arguments to maven, maybe profiles? run `mvn help:effective-pom` and `mvn help:effective-settings` to find out exactly what you run with; executing these targets on help plugin within STS could shed some light as well

Comment: What maven version are you using and what maven version is on the other computer?

Comment: It might be the case that somebody installed CUSTOM jars in their own repository; that's why it works if you copy their `.m2`folder.
I did experienced some corrupt jars with Maven, but nothing to the magnitude you describe.
Could it be that you're also using some custom repositories which create problems?
I'd suggest deleting your `.m2`, let Maven repopulate it and work on a case-by-case basis. Therefore: which jar creates problems? Is it a publicly-available jar, or is it your own? Does its md5 match the one you find in Maven Central, etc (i.e. figure out if the jar is the original)

Comment: My thoughts went to a local maven repo, or something else in settings.xml. Have you compared a 'vanilla' settings.xml to the one on the system that works as expected?

Comment: Also, this is quite the longshot, but occasionally antivirus could get in the way.

Comment: I came across many times this issue. Some time  transitive dependencies maven can't able to download.

Comment: I have seen something similar before, but that was because of conflicting maven versions, as I recall it.

Comment: @diginoise, I'm using the Maven that came with STS, I did not install it myself, and there's no `mvn` from the shell. Both computers are using the same STS version (3.9.0.RELEASE, based on Eclipse 4.6.3).
I will try and investigate which flags STS passes to Maven, and which version of Maven is installed.

Comment: Are you trying to download the files from the global mvnrepository or from one from your company?

Comment: @Christian, we don't have a local repository, we're using global ones.

Comment: @diginoise, I have no idea which flags STS passes to Maven, I couldn't find where they're listed.

Comment: The most important thing related to this is to start using a repository manager which solves most of the issues which are based on network issues ...

Comment: I would settle something that at least *reports* network errors, instead of turning them into compilation or even runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Maven 3.5.0 and told Eclipse to use it. For now it seems to be working.

Comment: Same thing it will not work if you do in `cmd` prompt

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps one thing you could do is to prevent maven from downloading snaphots, or explicitly define versions in your pom file for jar files which you are confident work. Within the repository tag you could add the snapshot tag. Maybe releases will be more stable.

```
<repository>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Comment: All dependencies have specific versions in the pom.xml file, and I'm sure the specified versions work. This is not a versioning problem or conflicting package problem - once Maven downloads everything properly, the system is working fine.